# Manage transaction with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm working on an project, and I use Hibernate+JPA to manage my DB.

But when I'm writing my service, I have to write something like that ALL THE TIME :

```
public String subscribe(String lastName, String firstName, String username, String borndate, String managerPwd) throws AuthenticationException, ExistingSubscriberException, SubscriberException, BadParametersException {
    try {
        this.authenticateMngr(managerPwd);

        this.em.getTransaction().begin();

        // Generate password and birthdate
        String password = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Calendar birthdate = CalendarManipulator.convertToCalendar(borndate);

        // Save player
        try {
            this.playerService.add(firstName, lastName, birthdate, username, password);
        } catch (PlayerAlreadyExistException e) {
            throw new ExistingSubscriberException();
        } catch (InvalidNameException | MinorPersonException | NullParameterException | InvalidPasswordException e) {
            throw new BadParametersException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.unexeptedException(e);
        }

        this.em.getTransaction().commit();

        return password;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        this.em.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This part of code :

```
public void function {
    try {
        this.em.getTransaction().begin();

        // .......

        this.em.getTransaction().commit();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        this.em.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I have to write it on each sevices... more than 50 :(

I'm not using Spring (I know some solutions exist for it), I'm using Hibernate + JPA alone in my project.

Do exist a solution to do the same thing without repeating myself :) ?

Ty

Comment: Yes if you use Spring it has annotation called @Transactional, it will do all these automatically.Look at here : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Comment: And if you are not using spring you could create a "Transactable" interface and pass it to an object whose only work is catching transaction failures and roll them back. With a factory should suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using plain Java - then yes, you should write this boilerplate code in every service. 
However you could use AOP, and create your own advice for declarative transaction demarcation.

Comment: Ok, I will see that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to write them over and over again. You can use the Spring framework to do this automatically. There is an annotation in the Spring framework called `@Transactional` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)

Comment: Understand and implement the Spring framwork will take me some hours :s. In fact I will be interested, but the code I'm writing is for a student project which I have to finish for tomorrow ^^'.

Comment: @graille The reason I do not recommend you because you tagged Spring and talked about learning Spring.Good luck